# How to set iphone tethering interface as default gateway

Tags: networking, routing

I am able to do the iphone usb tethering under ubuntu(11.10) which will be recognized as eth1 interface (I also have an eth0 internet connection).

What I want to do is, when the eth1 is up, I want to make it as the default gateway, and if eth1 is down, then return back to using eth0 as default gateway.

How can I make it happen?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the exact thing you are wanting on my laptop only using a droidX running on android but the basis is the same.  What you have to do is set up a bridge between your two interfaces so that they can share a single internet connection based on whichever one becomes active.  This is done by utilizing the bridge_ports option that is part of the bridge-utils package in ubuntu.  I have provided a link to show you how this is done in a few easy steps.

First install the bridge-utils PPA using the following command"

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

Then follow this link to assist you in setting it up by modifying your /etc/network/interfaces file
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html